# How can I debug "Unable to connect to the remote server" error after setting PayPal mode to 'security-test-sandbox'?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I'm using [PayPal .Net SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK). It was working well until I tried to test on a 'live' web server, I set the mode to 'security-test-sandbox'

```
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <!-- Replace the mode to `security-test-sandbox` to test if your server supports TLSv1.2. For more information follow README instructions.-->
      <add name="mode" value="security-test-sandbox" />
```

But now in C#, the bottom line of code...

```
    // Returns APIContext object
    public static APIContext GetApiContext()
    {
        // ### Api Context
        // Pass in a `APIContext` object to authenticate 
        // the call and to send a unique request id 
        // (that ensures idempotency). The SDK generates
        // a request id if you do not pass one explicitly.

        var config = getConfig();

        var tokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, clientSecret, config);
        string accessToken = tokenCredential.GetAccessToken();// this errors
```

...throws this error:

> PayPal.PayPalException: Retried 1 times.... Exception in PayPal.HttpConnection.Execute(). Check log for more details.

The problem is that the log doesn't give me any useful information, just "Unable to connect to the remote server":

> 2017-02-10 17:32:41,114 [10] DEBUG PayPal.Api.PayPalResource [(null)]
>   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> 2017-02-10 17:32:41,130 [10] DEBUG PayPal.Api.PayPalResource [(null)]
>   User-Agent:PayPalSDK/PayPal-NET-SDK 1.8.0
>   (lang=DOTNET;v=4.5.1;clr=4.0.30319.42000;bit=64;os=Microsoft Windows
>   NT 6.3.9600.0)
>
> 2017-02-10 17:32:41,130 [10] DEBUG PayPal.Api.PayPalResource [(null)]
>   Authorization:Basic QVV...MT3A=
>
> 2017-02-10 17:32:41,130 [10] DEBUG PayPal.Api.PayPalResource [(null)]
>   PayPal-Request-Id:9dc50c0e-e836-4a5d-a9c6-c6894c839c42
>
> 2017-02-10 17:32:42,594 [10] ERROR PayPal.Api.HttpConnection [(null)]
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> 2017-02-10 17:32:42,594 [10] DEBUG PayPal.Api.HttpConnection [(null)]
>   There was a problem connecting to the server: ConnectFailure
>
> ...

I've set up HTTPS on the web server using a self-signed certificate, and cloudflare.

[security details in google chrome's dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBxve.png)

The security should be sufficient to connect to PayPal, but I'm still unable.

I enabled logging to FailedReqLogFiles in IIS, and although there's an entry for the failed request, it says "No Errors or Warnings were found" in the "errors and warnings" section of the log.

How can I find out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

'security-test-sandbox' mode is no longer supported ([readme update](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/commit/bff7d63a0cbb2b1063bb75037a0e5c714d657e2d)).

Setting mode to 'live' or 'sandbox' works as expected.